# How to migrate SQL Server credentials from 2005 to 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, security, migration

I want to migrate SQL Server credentials used for proxy accounts from SQL Server 2005 to 2008 R2. Is there a way to decrypt credential passwords or a script to copy credential with the same password on new instance. Unfortunately I don't have the passwords for the accounts used for SQL credentials. So looking for a workaround.

Comment: See if [Get-MSSQLCredentialPasswords.psm1](https://github.com/NetSPI/Powershell-Modules/blob/master/Get-MSSQLCredentialPasswords.psm1) helps.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you take a look at the [Copy-DbaCredential](https://dbatools.io/functions/copy-dbacredential/) Powershell cmdlet from [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/).

From their web page on this cmdlet:

> By using password decryption techniques provided by Antti Rantasaari
>   (NetSPI, 2014), this script migrates SQL Server Credentials from one
>   server to another, while maintaining login names and passwords.

Here is an example of how you'd invoke this cmdlet

```
Copy-DbaCredential -Source sqlserver2014a -Destination sqlcluster
```

Comment: FYI.. there is an issue if credential has [] .. see https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/issues/2560